# How can I check if my WCF service works with any binding when implementing IDispatchMessageInspectors

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I am working with a WCF service which has mutiple end points. I have implemented methods from `BehaviorExtensionElement`, `IServiceBehavior`, `IDispatchMessageInspector` for inspecting the message headers before processing each request. I tested it and it works fine with `wsHttpBinding`.

I want to make sure if my service (as it has message Inspectors) works just fine with `NetTcpBinding`, `NamedPipe` and other kind of bindings as well. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

IDispatchMessageInspector is used is to inspect or modify inbound or outbound application messages either prior to dispatching a request message to an operation or before returning a reply message to a caller.

Message inspectors are higher up the stack (at the dispatch level) so which binding is used by the endpoint will not matter.

For example:

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
   foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase cdb in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
   {
         var cd = cdb as ChannelDispatcher;

         if (cd != null)
         {
            foreach (var ed in cd.Endpoints)
            {
               ed.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new AuthorizationHeaderGetter());
               ed.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = new UserTokenInjector(serviceDescription.ServiceType);
            }
         }
   }
}
```

There is no mention of “kind” of binding (wsHttp or NetTcp) in the code above.

As to your question how to test this, I not sure what you would be testing. There is nothing to test in the ApplyDispatchBehavior (except WCF framework). You could write unit test to test your IDispatchMessageInspector  class.